# Google Cast Default Receiver text track not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I'm building a Chrome sender app for the Google Cast/Chromecast using the Default Media Receiver. I've been following [this guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_advanced) and apparently text tracks are supposed to work with the Default Receiver:

> Note: Currently, the Styled and Default Media Receivers allow you to use only the text tracks with the API. To work with the audio and video tracks, you must develop a Custom Receiver.

I have CORS enabled on my server and everything else works just fine. Before enabling CORS the media wouldn't load at all. The tracks related code looks like this:

```
var englishSubtitle = new chrome.cast.media.Track(1, chrome.cast.media.TrackType.TEXT);
englishSubtitle.trackContentId = 'http://localhost:8000/assets/caption_en.vtt';
englishSubtitle.trackContentType = 'text/vtt';
englishSubtitle.subtype = chrome.cast.media.TextTrackType.SUBTITLES;
englishSubtitle.name = 'English Subtitles';
englishSubtitle.language = 'en-US';
englishSubtitle.customData = null;

var tracks = [englishSubtitle];
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(videoURL);
mediaInfo.contentType = 'video/mp4';
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
mediaInfo.customData = null;
mediaInfo.streamType = chrome.cast.media.StreamType.BUFFERED;
mediaInfo.textTrackStyle = new chrome.cast.media.TextTrackStyle();
mediaInfo.duration = null;
mediaInfo.tracks = tracks;
```

Then I add the following lines to set the active track and load the media.

```
var activeTrackIds = [1];
mediaInfo.activeTrackIds = activeTrackIds;
var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
castSession.loadMedia(request).then(onLoadSuccess, onLoadError);
```

I can't figure out why this code isn't working. I'm not getting any errors and I've tried pretty much everything I can think of. The video plays, but the subtitles aren't showing.

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_advanced#cors_requirements), Google Cast requires the presence of CORS headers, but even simple mp4 media streams require CORS if they include Tracks. `"If you want to enable Tracks for any media, you must enable CORS for both your track streams and your media streams"`.

Comment: @KENdi Yes, CORS is enabled on the server where both media are stored.